# Global PHP "sort through" vs other fields

Tags: 7, entities

In drupal views, you can create a field called "global php" and insert your own php code. Also as well, it has a sort feature which is handy when your view style is a table.

However, the other fields does not have a "sort" feature on them. Is there a way to add it to them? Or does it just have to come with it, like global php does?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be supported by the module supplying the field. In [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7), each defined field has a `'sort'` element that defines the sort handler function for the field.